# Reaction time not normally distributed

Tags: r, normal-distribution, t-test, normality-assumption, group-differences

I am trying to analyze a dataset. My independent variable (IV) is instructing participants to think fast or slow and my dependent variable (DV) is participants' average reaction time. As expected, the average reaction time is not normally distributed. I'm trying to run a $t$-test but if the data is not normally distributed at all I'm not sure how to approach this. Here's an example of the distribution of average reaction time for one for one of the groups:

[image]

And I'm not sure if removing outliers is the best approach as the groups were instructed to think fast or slow.

Comment: To be clear, this is the distribution of response times for all participants or one group? Do you have more than two groups? Please share some other summary statistics such as the group sample sizes and the sample variances.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hick%27s_law and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitts%27s_law provide subject-area guidance.  Both suggest formulating hypotheses and analyzing data in terms of the logarithms of the reaction times rather than the times themselves.